# how can I solve this integral

Tags: integration

I've been solving a differential problem and finally reached to below statement.Please help me through solving this integral :

$$\int \frac{1-x}{(x+1)^2}\text{d}x $$

Comment: Can you please explain It more?(please leave an answer,if you can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = x+1 \implies du = \,dx$, and $x= u-1$ so $1-x = 1-(u-1) = 2-u$

Then you get the integral $$\int \frac{2-u}{u^{2}}\,du = \int \left(\frac 2{u^{2}} - \frac 1u \right) du = \int \left(2u^{-2} - \frac 1u\right)\,du=  -2u^{-1} - \ln |u| +C$$

Comment: dont you want $u^2?$

Comment: Thank you amWhy...(2 thumbs up)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to back-substitute $u = x+1$!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{1-x}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{-(x+1)+2}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the following Ansatz:

$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}= \frac{A}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{B}{x+1} = \frac{B(x+1)+A}{(x+1)^2} = {{(A+B)+Bx}\over(x+1)^2}= \frac{1-x}{(x+1)^2}.$$

We equate coefficients to solve for the constants $A$ and $B$ simultaneously, ie
$$A+B = 1 \\ B = -1$$
and integrate elementarily.

Comment: I understand your solution, but what would be answer by this method?if we use (x=-1) then "A" would be equal to 0 and what about B?(B=?)

Answer (score 0):

$\bf hint:$ write $$\frac{1- x}{(1+x)^2 }= \frac{2 -(1+x)}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{2}{(1+x)^2} - \frac 1{1+x} $$

edit:  use $\int\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} = -\frac{1}{1+x}, \int\frac{dx}{1+x} = \ln|1+x|$